# Facebook applinking doesn't open the apps

Tags: android, facebook, applinks

I have implemented facebook applink, and it seems to be work. When i share a link from facebook, it open dialog that confirm to open with the apps. But install or compile from android studio, the alert still appears. I have checked the package name is same between in the web meta tag and android application.

Have anyone found this issue, and found solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can host a webpage contains applink meta to test whether your applik is working.